# ¿Cómo marcar una cadena de caracteres en mayúscula compuesta por varias palabras?

Tags: javascript, espacio-de-nombres

No se cómo marcar nombres compuestos en mayúsculas de tal manera que salga como una solo coincidencia y no una por cada parte del nombre. Lo máximo que he conseguido ha sido:

```
/[A-Z]+([A-Z][a-záéúíó]*)/
```

Comment: ¿Y no sería mejor convertir todo a mayúsculas o minúsculas y después realizar el match? O acaso buscas exclusivamente un patrón? En todo caso una regex siempre es un último recurso, nunca el primero.

Comment: Hola, Mauricio, gracias por contestar. Lo que debo hacer es, a través de una expresión lógica, encontrar las palabras (nombres) escritos por completo en mayúsculas que aparecen en el texto. El problema es que algunos de esos nombres están compuestos por varias palabras, por ejemplo DON QUIJOTE DE LA MACHA. Y con la expresión que tengo actualmente me hace un match con cada palabra del nombre, no con el nombre completo.

Comment: Ok, en todo caso, no es un *nombre* lo que buscas, ya que eso requiere una lógica bastante mayor, buscas *todas* las palabras que tengan todos sus caracteres en mayúscula (según lo que aportas en tu comentario). Es eso?

Comment: Sí, correcto, eso mismo es lo que necesito

Comment: El hecho es que necesito que esas palabras (o nombres propios compuestos) me aparezcan marcados como una sola cadena. Es decir, en el caso de DON QUIJOTE DE LA MANCHA quiero que me lo marque como 1 match y no 5 match.

Answer (score 0):

No se si entiendo bien la pregunta, si lo que quieres es detectar unicamente una palabra con la primera en mayuscula, funcionaria con

```
/[A-Z]+([a-záéúíó]*)/
```

Por ejemplo:

```
"se llama Emilio Juan Gonzale".match(/[A-Z]+[a-záéúíó]*/)
// Encontraria "Emilio"
```

No se si te referias a eso, espero que te sirva

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias, Martín, pero lo que estoy intentado conseguir es lo que le acabo de explicar a Mauricio en el comentario de arriba. No sé si así se entiende mejor mi problema.